# How to convert double value to uint8_t string[] to print on terminal window in atmel studio

Tags: c, double, typeconverter, atmelstudio, uint8t

I am trying to convert some double values to uint8_t String[] (in C) when programming in Atmel Studio 6.2 in order to use it further in function: `usart_write_buffer_job`.

And this is the whole command I am going to use further, but instead of characters, I would like to print the given double values on the screen:

```
   uint8_t string[] = "Hello World!\n";
   usart_write_buffer_job(&usart_instance, string, sizeof(string));
```

I have tried casting, but it does not work properly in Atmel, as it does not recognize the `(uint8_t*)(&MyDoubleValue)`

Comment: are you looking for [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)?

Comment: Why are you using an array of `uint8_t` rather than an array of `char`? And what do you mean by "does not recognize"? Please include the error message in your question.

Comment: The `usart_write_buffer_job` is only accepting const *uint8_t as argument and the error says uint8_t is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for `snprintf`:

```
double d;
char string[50];
snprintf(string, 50, "%f", d);
```

Comment: snprintf is not proparly working in this case, as I need a uint8_t string[]  as input argument. At the end the idea is to print the value as a human readable ascii one in terminal window.

Comment: A `char []` should be castable to a `uint8_t []` without issue, particularly if it's a printable ASCII string.

Comment: @MRM Forget snprintf and use a simple for loop to copy the values to the char array which you then nul terminate.

Comment: @this The initial value is a `double`, so you can't copy values from that to a char array.  `snprintf` is needed to create a decimal representation of it.  Either the array is `char []` and you cast it when calling `usart_write_buffer_job`, or it's `uint8_t []` and you cast it when caling `snprintf`.

Comment: I could cast it to `char []` now, but still the following casting from `char []` to `uint8_t []` does not work properly in Atmel.   `uint8_t arrString[10];`
 `for(int i=0; i<10; i++){arrString[i] =(uint8_t)(string[i]); }` and then   `printf("%d\n",arrString[1]); `

Comment: @MRM I don't think that `printf` is doing what you expect.  The `%d` specifier expects an `int` argument and prints it in decimal format.  You're passing it a `uint8_t` i.e. an `unsigned char`, which happens to contain one of the characters in the decimal representation of the number in question.  To print it properly, you should do `printf("%s\n",arrString);`

Comment: Thanks :) now it works in mingw32. But still not appearing on Terminal Window of Atmel Studio when I use `usart_write_buffer_job(&usart_instance, arrString, sizeof(arrString));`